# Unable to set GregorianCalendar Month and Date

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

Im trying to set the month and date of a Gregorian Calendar:

```
GregorianCalendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();

startCalendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 3);
System.out.println(startCalendar.MONTH);
startCalendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 9);
System.out.println(startCalendar.DATE);
```

The output is:

```
2
5
```

It doesn't seem to matter which numbers i use (ie. if i replace the 3 and 9), it always has the same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References:

- [GregorianCalendar (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)
- [Calendar (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

`MONTH` and `DATE` are field numbers and aren't the actual value of the fields. You should use `get()` method to get the number set.

```
GregorianCalendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();

startCalendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 3);
System.out.println(startCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
startCalendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 9);
System.out.println(startCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

`startCalendar.MONTH` is the same as [`Calendar.MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), and is a static field [declared](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java#l381) in the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class as:

```
public final static int MONTH = 2;
```

To get the month from the calendar, you need to call [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-):

```
startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

Note that you should always qualify static fields by the *actual* class declaring them (e.g. `Calendar.MONTH`), never by a reference variable (e.g. `startCalendar.MONTH`) and never by subclass (e.g. `GregorianCalendar.MONTH`).

So, your code should be:

```
GregorianCalendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();

startCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
System.out.println(startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
startCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 9);
System.out.println(startCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
```