# applying Gregorian Calendar in JAVA

Tags: java, datetime, gregorian-calendar, java-calendar

```
import  java.util.GregorianCalendar ;
public class MyCalendar extends  GregorianCalendar  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
           MyCalendar a = new MyCalendar();
           System.out.println(a.getCurrenttime());
}

public String getCurrenttime(){
     String time= YEAR+"-"+(MONTH+1)+"-"+DATE+"-"+HOUR+"-"+MINUTE+"-"+SECOND; 
     return time;}}
```

However, it always show the same time. What have I done wrong.

P.S. it is intended not to use command like gettime() directely. The string should remain there.

Comment: It’s really not a strong case for inheritance. Prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Why are you still using the long outdated `GregorianCalendar` class? The modern `ZonedDateTime` is much nicer to work with, and for one thing wouldn’t make it possible to make a bug like the one in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set GregorianCalendar Month and Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110408/unable-to-set-gregoriancalendar-month-and-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using YEAR, MONTH... and so on, Here you are accessing static fields inherited from the GregorianCalendar class.
However, you have to access the fields of your Calendar using these variables in somthing like this :

```
     public String getCurrenttime(){

    String time= this.get(YEAR)+"-"+(this.get(MONTH)+1)+"-"+
            this.get(DATE)+"-"+this.get(HOUR_OF_DAY)+"-"+this.get(MINUTE)+"-"+this.get(SECOND);
    return time;
}
```

Comment: I know this fact. What I mean is I cannot use method like gettime() to get the answer directly. I need to use the string method to get a string. And then print out the string

Comment: @YuiHongNg I edited the answer, it may help.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help

Comment: I suspect you meant `this.get(HOUR_OF_DAY)`, not `this.get(HOUR)`? I know the bug was already in the question.

Comment: @OleV.V. you are right, thanks for pointing on that fact !

Answer (score 0):

Your title says “applying `GregorianCalendar`”, and that’s not what I am doing in this answer. While [mustabelMo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304049/5772882) is correct, I wanted to show you how IMHO your task is best solved, and the first point is I recommend you don’t use the long outdated `GregorianCalendar` class. Today we have so much better in [the modern Java date and time API known as `java.time` or JSR-310](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For your need, you may use a `LocalDateTime`:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MyCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCalendar a = new MyCalendar();
        System.out.println(a.getCurrentTime());
    }

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d-H-m-s");
    private LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    private String getCurrentTime() {
        return now.format(formatter);
    }

}
```

The program prints something like

```
2017-11-15-11-59-1
```

Other points to note:

Prefer composition over inheritance. Rather than inheriting from whatever class you use for getting calendar data, it’s better style to encapsulate an object of that class inside your class.

Use a formatter for formatting your date-time into a string, it’s more convenient and easier to change if you want a different format. For example, many will prefer to have the minutes and seconds printed in two digits always, with a leading zero as necessary. To obtain this, just use two format pattern letters instead of one:

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d-H-mm-ss");
```

Now the output goes like

```
2017-11-15-12-03-01
```

In the code I use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to pick up the JVM’s time zone setting. This is fragile, it may be changed behind your back without notice. If you can, prefer a specific time zone in the *region/city* format, for example:

```
private LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
```

Despite the name `getCurrentTime()` gives you the time the `MyCalendar` object was created, not the time the method was called. If you prefer the latter, just create a new `LocalDateTime` object within the method.

You may prefer to use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` since these include a time zone and an offset from UTC, respectively. It’s often considered bad practice to throw this information away even when you don’t see any immediate use for it.